# #Error using RowCount in Iif-Statement (if Countrows = 0)

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, dataset, ssrs-2008, iif

Please review my following statement:

```
=Iif(Cint(CountRows("TdsTemp")) > 0,
     //Show some data here
 ,CStr("No Results"))
```

This is the expression behind my Textbox.

**Case 1: **
If my TdsTemp contains more than 1 row the correct data is shown.

**Case 2: **
If my TdsTemp contains 0 rows then I get the following msg `#Error` instead of the expected `NoResults`.

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Why is my `false-part` not working? If you have any other means to check if there is content in the tds then please share.

Thanks.

**Note:** The part 'Show some data here' worked before impletementing the Iif-statement as mentionned above.

**Update:** Setting `Cint(CountRows("TdsTemp"))` as expression for textbox did produce the desireably result

Comment: try removing the `cstr("No Results")` and just display `"No Results"`

Comment: Same Result. Even removing the Cint() around CountRows didn't resolve the issue

Comment: whats the data type of that report column? are you formatting in report?

Comment: TdsTemp is my dataset. "//Show some data here" worked before using the  iif statement. So i don't see how this is relevant. If need i will add  it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ISNOTHING Function, change field accordingly & use column which always has some value when record count > 0

=IIF(ISNothing(Fields!PKey.Value),"No Result",//Show some data here)